# In PHP, how do you output JSON iterating first on a child array, then on parent?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have tried for several weeks to get this to work, and have given in.  I need to display the following array in JSON.

As you can see, [coloroptions] is itself a JSON array, making this a multidimensional array.  The trick is (I think) to iterate over the array, first on the child [coloroptions], then on the parent. I am probably way off base, though.  Has anyone done anything like this?

Thank you, in advance!

**SAMPLE DATA** from print_r()

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [automobile] => 'Mustang'
                [coloroptions] => [{"color":"red"},{"color":"blue"},{"color":"green"}]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [automobile] => 'Camero'
                [coloroptions] =>  [{"color":"red"},{"color":"orange"}]
            )
    )
```

**JSON output**

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "automobile": "Mustang",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "automobile": "Mustang",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "automobile": "Mustang",
            "color": "green"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "automobile": "Camero",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "automobile": "Camero",
            "color": "orange"
        },
    ]
```

Comment: The "JSON Output" is the desired output?

Comment: Yes, the JSON in the example is what I am trying to achieve with the data provided.  The project is much more in depth, but with a basic understanding of how to approach it will send me in the right direction.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close! My approach would be to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the colours, and iterate over them like a normal PHP array.

```
// First, start by looping through each 'parent':
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    // Decode the json color array into a normal php array
    $colorarray = json_decode($value['coloroptions'], true);

    /* Loop through each of the colours.
       (Note that they'll be a few layers deep. 
       Do a print_r($colorarray) to see it's structure)  */
    foreach($colorarray as $color)
    {
       // And build your output array:
        $output[] = array(
            "id" => $value['id'], 
            "automobile" => $value['automobile'],
            "color" => $color['color']
        );
    }
}
```

To check the final PHP array you can `print_r($output)`. To convert `$output` into a json array, use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , you need to `json_decode` the coloroptions and output the assembled array  with colors inside it to the result array.

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'id'           => 1,
        'automobile'   => 'Mustang',
        'coloroptions' => '[{"color":"red"},{"color":"blue"},{"color":"green"}]'
        ),
    array(
        'id'           => 2,
        'automobile'   => 'Camero',
        'coloroptions' => '[{"color":"red"},{"color":"orange"}]'
        ),
    );

$result = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $coloroptions = json_decode($value['coloroptions']);
    foreach($coloroptions as $color){
        $result[] = array(
            'id'         => $value['id'],
            'automobile' => $value['automobile'],
            'color'      => $color->color,
            );
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($result));
```

see the example [here](https://3v4l.org/dctG7)

Comment: Brilliant!  You solved in minutes what has been bugging me for weeks.  This worked perfectly.  Thank you for the sandbox example. The biggest piece I was missing was json_decode on the child.